# MySQL - Column value depends on values from two different tables

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a MySQL database that contains these tables (* denotes primary key):

**`TableA`:**

```
----------------------------------------------
|  *id  |  time  |  price  |  special_price  |
----------------------------------------------
```

**`TableB`:**

```
-------------------------------------
|  *table_a_id  |  *date  |  price  |
-------------------------------------
```

**`SpecialDate`:**

```
--------------------------
|  *date  |  description |
--------------------------
```

The value of `TableB.price` column of each entry in `TableB` will be either `TableA.price` or `TableA.special_price` of the corresponding `TableA` entry, depending on whether `TableB.date` is a special date or not (whether `TableB.date` exists in the `SpecialDate` table).

This design, as it stands, doesn't feel right as every time I'm adding a record to `TableB`, I have to look up the date from `SpecialDate` to see if it's a special date or not, then look up the corresponding entry from `TableA` to get the value for the `price` column. And every time a record from `SpecialDate` gets added or updated, I have to go over every entry in `TableB` to update its `price` column.

I'm thinking the column `TableB.price` should be removed and calculated when needed but I'm not sure how to do that using SQL. I have a lot of views that depend on that `price` column, for example:

**`TableAFullView`:**

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  id  |  time  |  count_of_table_b_instances  |  sum_of_table_b_instances  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Where `count_of_table_b_instances` is the number of `TableB` entries that point to this `TableA` entry and `sum_of_table_b_instances` is the sum of their prices.

With my original design, this view is simple to implement and it performs well. But if I get rid of the column `TableB.price`, how would I implement this view? Will the performance take a hit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> With my original design, this view is simple to implement and it performs well. But if I get rid of the column TableB.price, how would I implement this view

```
create table TableA (
id int,
v_time date,
price int,
special_price int
);

create table TableB (
table_a_id int,
v_date date
);

create table SpecialDate (
v_date date,
description varchar(5)
);

insert into TableA values (1,'2019-09-01', 10, 5);
insert into TableB values (1,'2019-10-01');
insert into TableB values (1,'2019-11-01');

insert into TableA values (2,'2019-12-01', 50, 1);
insert into TableB values (2,'2019-12-02');
insert into TableB values (2,'2019-12-03');
insert into TableB values (2,'2019-11-01');

insert into SpecialDate values('2019-11-01', 'sale');

--your view definition

select a.id,
   a.v_time,
   count(*) as count_of_table_b_instances,
   sum(
      case
     when s.v_date is not null then a.special_price
     else a.price
     end
   ) as sum_of_table_b
 from TableA a
 join TableB b
   on a.id = b.table_a_id
 left join SpecialDate s
  on b.v_date = s.v_date
 group by a.id,
      a.v_time
```

> Will the performance take a hit?

I can't say for sure because I can't assume you have the right indexes setup to support this query without seeing the DDL of the tables. If you have indexes in place to support the join clauses, or if you don't have much data in these tables, I don't think you would take a performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest set up is probably something like this:

Table A

```
-----------------------------
|  *id  |  time  |  price  |  
-----------------------------
```

Table B

```
------------------------------------------------------------
|  *id  |  table_a_id(f)  | start_date | end_date | price  |  
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Which you can then query like this:

```
SELECT
    table_a.id
    , time
    , coalesce(table_b.price, table_a.price) as price
    , start_date
    , end_date
FROM
    table_a
    left join table_b on table_a.id = table_b.table_a_id
WHERE
    NOW() between start_date and end_date
```

If you want to 'group' special's together, you could do this:

Table A

```
-----------------------------
|  *id  |  time  |  price  |  
-----------------------------
```

Table B

```
------------------------------------------------------------
|  *id  |  table_a_id(f)  | table_c_id(f) | price  |  
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Table C

```
------------------------------------------------------------
|  *id  |  details | start_date | end_date |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

And query it like:

```
SELECT
    table_a.id
    , time
    , table_c.details
    , coalesce(table_b.price, table_a.price) as price
    , start_date
    , end_date
FROM
    table_a
    left join table_b on table_a.id = table_b.table_a_id
    left join table_c on table_c.id = table_b.table_c_id
WHERE
    NOW() between start_date and end_date
```